# Why is the css defined area locked? (css3/tabbed)

Tags: css

I'm playing with tabbed css from http://css-tricks.com/examples/CSSTabs/:

Example six

```
.w3c { min-height: 250px; position: relative; width: 100%; }
.w3c > div { display: inline; }
.w3c > div > a { margin-left: -1px; position: relative; left: 1px; text-decoration: none; color: black; background: white; display: block; float: left; padding: 5px 10px; border: 1px solid #ccc; border-bottom: 1px solid white; }
.w3c > div:not(:target) > a { border-bottom: 0; background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, white, #eee); }   
.w3c > div:target > a { background: white; }    
.w3c > div > div { background: white; z-index: -2; left: 0; top: 30px; bottom: 0; right: 0; padding: 20px; border: 1px solid #ccc; }    
.w3c > div:not(:target) > div { position: absolute }
.w3c > div:target > div { position: absolute; z-index: -1; }
```

This creates a tabbed area, but nothing I put inside a tab is manipulable: I can't highlight, I can't create a link. I'm not sure what is going entirely, just picked this example because it is concise. Can any css expert explain why I can't seem to do anything with this.

Note: it works perfectly for my needs, except I can't put anything in the tabs except plain text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `z-index` of the last rule to `0` and you should be able to interact with the tab's contents again:

```
.w3c > div:target > div { position: absolute; z-index: 0; }
```

Having a negative `z-index` means anything with a zero or positive `z-index` will overlap the tab. One of those things may very well be the page `body`, which then results in "disabling" the tab content.

Comment: I realize that the borders separating the tabs and the content won't look right, but they didn't look right in the beginning. I'm not sure of the fix for that though.

Comment: Thank you...I had worked with the z-index of the block I was putting in to no avail, and I'm just deciphering what this css actually does.